# XCode 7.1.1 always indexing

Tags: xcode, xcode7.1, sourcekit

I am typing one character into a code and XCode starts indexing , processing files. This for about 30 seconds and in this time it is nearly unusable. The SourcekitService is on high CPU during indexing.
I already tried to disable Indexing by

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

but it did not work for me.

Any hints howto get better performance for XCode 7.1. Its unusable like this.

Comment: I suggest to update your xcode to last version 7.2

Comment: Updated. Its the same. During typing only one character it is already parsing and typing is stopped for 1-2 seconds.

Comment: It's very strange... Try to remove completely xcode (I don't know if is there a way to remove all components from the Mac) and reinstall it... Probably there is something in the system that not allows xcode to work fine. Another solution (but very hard) is backup your data and re-init the Mac with a clear installation of OS.

Comment: Disabling Source Control fixed. At least until Apple fix the bug.

Comment: @Lorenzo, that is not a Windows, lol.